# Excel: Break on Error doesn't work in user-defined function

Tags: debugging, excel, excel-2003, runtime-error, vba

It seems that when VBA code is called from a cell formula (ie. a "User Defined Function" or UDF), the usual VBA Break On Error doesn't work.

The only place I can find this behavior documented is a couple of lines in an article called ["Developing User-Defined Functions for Excel 2007 and Excel Services"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226683%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

> Error handling returns #VALUE errors. All exceptions thrown by the UDF code are returned into the Excel worksheet as #VALUE errors.

Even if you set Error Trapping to "Break on All Errors" and single-step your code**, you will never see the VBA Run-time Error dialog - Excel just quietly abandons execution without telling you what went wrong. Of course this makes debugging more difficult than it needs to be.

There are some potential workarounds involving `On Error` but I'd rather not clutter up my code just to find out where an error was raised.

Is there some Excel / VBA option I've overlooked which will make Break On Error work normally? I'm using Excel 2003.

** The only way to get into the debugger when called from a cell is to set a breakpoint or use a `Stop` statement

Answer (score 3):

Best method would be to use the `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` with a `Stop` reference followed by `Resume`.

Need to be careful not to get into an infinite loop with `resume` as UDFs run almost continually (if this happens hit `Esc` repeatedly)

So in your code add: `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` near the start of your function and then right at the end before `End Function`:

```
Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Source & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Stop
Resume
```

The `Exit Function` stops this code running in normal operation.
If an error is encountered a messagebox with the details will pop up, the code will break (due to `Stop`) and you can step through back into your code (hopping back via the `resume` statement) using the next line command on the debug toolbar.

Of course don't forget to comment out the `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` line when you're happy with your UDF.

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware that it isn't any fun hearing this when you specifically asked for something else than `On Error`, but I'm afraid it's the only option to my knowledge.

You could just use `On Error Goto ErrorHandler` while debugging (and comment it out to get the default `On Error Goto 0` at other times). The `ErrorHandler` could have just a couple of lines so it doesn't clutter up your code too much:

```
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Source & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Resume
```

always with a breakpoint on `Resume` to guide you back to the error-causing statement upon stepping -- and to avoid an infinite error-handling loop.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently also.  I really thought something had changed and it didn't always work like this -but I guess I was wrong.

Below is a perhaps a small improvement on what has been suggested.  I added a Debug? prompt to the message box so that you can either debug or not.  So no infinite loops.  And the line causing the error is highlighted.

Say this is my original function:

```
Function MyFunction(input_value)
   a = 1
   b = 1 / 0
   MyFunction = 1 + input_value ^ 2
End Function
```

If I suspect a problem, then I'll add three lines like this:

```
Function MyFunction(input_value)
On Error GoTo DebugError
    a = 1
    b = 1 / 0
    MyFunction = 1 + input_value ^ 2
Exit Function
DebugError: If MsgBox(Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Debug(F8,F8)?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then Stop: Resume
End Function
```

Then when an error happens:

1. A message box pops up with the error.
2. You click YES to debug, or NO to continue.
3. Clicking YES opens the VBA code.
4. Press F8 twice to highlight the line causing the error.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S708z.png)

This is some trouble, but not too bad.  If an error happens while you're debugging, it's no problem.  You just hit F8, YES, F8, F8 to get to back in.

Note that Error Trapping must be set to Break on Unhandled Errors, or Break in Class Module.